# Cauchy mean value theorem, finding the function $\frac{f(c) - f(a) }{g(b) -g(c)} = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$ exist for all $x\in[a,b]$ and if $g'(x)$ does not vanish any where on $(a,b)$ then prove that for some $C\in(a,b)$ 
>   $$\frac{f(c) - f(a) }{g(b) -g(c)}  = \frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$

In solving these type of question we need to consider a function. I want to know is there any specific method to find that function which is used to prove above type of equations or i have to learn its solution? Please explain the method if any.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use Rolle’s theorem, so we have to build a function $F$ such that applying to it Rolle’s theorem provides us with Cauchy’s MVT.

How can we prove Lagrange’s MVT from Rolle’s theorem? We consider $F(x)=f(x)-kx$ and choose $k$ so that the hypotheses of Rolle’s theorem apply: $F(a)=f(a)-ka$, $F(b)=f(b)-kb$, so we need
$$
f(b)-kb=f(a)-ka
$$
which means
$$
k=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
Now the further step is easy: use $F(x)=f(x)-kg(x)$. We want
$$
f(a)-kg(a)=f(b)-kg(b)
$$
and therefore
$$
k=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}
$$
Note that $g(b)\ne g(a)$ because, by assumption, the derivative $g'$ doesn't vanish over $(a,b)$.

Since Rolle’s theorem provides $c\in(a,b)$ where $F'(c)=0$, we have
$$
f'(c)-\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}g'(c)=0
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(b)-g(a)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}
$$

The trick is essentially forming a linear combination of $f$ and $g$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** WLOG let $f(a)+g(a)\leq  f(b)+g(b)$ and then apply **Roll** theorem with
$$h(x)=\ln\Big[\big((f(x)-f(a)\big)\big(g(x)-g(b)\big)\Big]$$
on $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

I won't propose any proof of the statement, since it is clear that this would *not* be what you are looking for.

Shortly, the answer to your question can't be but negative. There is no general strategy to prove a statement: experience and efforts are the only ingredient you must add to your recipe!

Experience often offers *standard* approaches: after you have studied many proofs in your books, you should have a set of tools that *may* apply to your own statement.
Efforts cannot be dispensed with: proving a theorem is a difficult taks, and sometimes you must try several ideas before you isolate a working one.

In you example, the smart trick of the proof is exactly the definition of the good function. Proofs are a crative job, and you can't reduce them to a set of rigid rules.